# Set ng-href to current page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

Is it possible to set ng-href to go to the current page?

eg:

```
<a ng-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ window.location.href }}">facebook</a>
```

When the above runs, I keep getting:

```
<a ng-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=">facebook</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by Current page?

Comment: How are you setting value to `window.location.href` ? This sure doesn't look like native JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting value to `window.location.href` ? This sure doesn't look like native JS.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr47du8o/1/) to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Aniket.  That's exactly what I ended up doing half an hour after I asked the question.  Before that, I was beating around the bush hoping that by putting {{ window.location.href }}, it would automatically compute the js within the double brackets.  :P

Answer (score -2):

ng-href is part of AngularJS and there are a few ways to point to the same page. The method I use do not include the domain so the Angular Router will direct it as needed, like the following.

```
ng-href="/mySubDomain"
```

The Docs go into detail about this and give a nice code sample that shows you what you should expect from the route change.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref